# How to Prevent Uninstalling Chrome Extension on macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, preferences, plist, chrome-extensions

There is an extension that I want to make harder to delete or disable on Chrome, how can I go about doing this? I have tried to edit the ExtensionInstallForcelist policy using:

`defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallForcelist -array "blaaajhemilngeeffpbfkdjjoefldkok;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"`

but I can still delete or disable the extension. Furthermore, the level is set to "Recommended" instead of "Mandatory". How could I fix this?

Comment: As an admin, you can always undo anything you do. You'd need to use a standard account to be able to fully lock anything.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to make it harder to remove than just going to the extension list and pressing "Remove from Chrome"

Comment: If you have authority, then of course it's just going to let you.